# Add a telecommuting search option to the Careers site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, search

I realized I had posted this as a comment to the blog post when it should have posted it here:

Is there a way to add a telecommuting search option to the new jobs/career site? I found a few positions listed with their location as "Telecommute" but if you type that in the where search box, you get a lot of results back, some of which don’t even contain telecommute in the description.

All in all looking good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Dillie-O, we've added telecommute as a search option.

Comment: Am I the only one who imagined the first two words of this response in a Ned Flanders voice?

Comment: Happy to help! 
@Randolpho: Most okily-dokily-iddily-dillie-o! 8^D